# Simple JS slideshow that will work with N entries

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I would like to create a simple javascript slideshow that allows a user to click 'Previous' or 'Next' and have the element slide in from the right or left depending. Content will be coming in from a CMS, so it's not 'hard-coded' persay. My markup would look like this ideally (where the most recent entry receives the 'show' class):

```
<span class="back"><a href="#">Previous slide</a></span>
<span class="next"><a href="#">Next Slide</a></span>
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="client show">
    <p>Yada</p>
    </div>
    <div class="client hide">
    <p>Yada</p>
    </div>
    <div class="client hide">
    <p>Yada</p>
    </div>
    <div class="client hide">
    <p>Yada</p>
    </div>
 </div><!--end slideshow-->
```

I need something that will automatically detect order and allow the number of .client classes to be anything. This seems very close: http://jsbin.com/ekecu but I don't want it to be based on visible links to switch, just the same absolutely positioned previous and next buttons.

Would really appreciate some help, or if you were feeling especially generous an source snippet I could use.

Answer (score 0):

[Shadow Box](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) or [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)?

Comment: Those are pop-up 'lightbox-esc' scripts, I need a slider.